# How to connect Appium to Visual Studio 2019 on MAC?

Tags: macos, appium, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to do a test project in Visual Studio with Appium, however I am working in MAC and I am totally lost, I do not know how to make the links between each one (Appium and Visual Studio 2019). Could someone give me an example or a guide on how to generate this. I already have everything installed, I just need a little guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time already, in the end I managed to do it this way, I used Android Studio to load the SDKs and then with Appium a session must be created, the necessary characteristics of the controller are placed and the connection will be made successfully. Maybe this can help others.